# Openlayers stop zoomstart event

Tags: events, zooming, openlayers, gis

I work with `Openlayers 2.x` and I have `zoomstart` event

```
  map.events.register('zoomstart', map, function(e) {

            // 1. OpenLayers.Event.stop(event);
            // 2. return ;
            // 3. e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

My way (1,2,3) not working and event does not stop and change zoom level. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I am not clear why you would want to stop a zoom start event you have explicitly added. Could you explain more?

Comment: Thank you for reply. For me editing level is 13 . Can you imagine process , user is editing geometry , he stand on  zoom level 13 , zoom out , I want to ignore zoom out because it is not zoom level

Comment: You mean that zoom should only work in zoom level 13 and not in any others?

Comment: Sorry, I am still unclear. There is no zoomstart event in the map class. Are you saying you want to disable accidentally clicking on the zoomBar control while editing if zoom level is 13 or higher?

Comment: I want to kill zoom event in zoomstart event

Answer (score 0):

The zoom event is triggered by the zoomBarUp function in PanZoomBar control, see: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/PanZoomBar.js and the line

```
this.map.zoomTo(zoomLevel);
```

One way to prevent zoom for zoom levels above 13 would be to override this function, which you can do by adding your own version, either in a standalone js file or by using prototype within you OpenLayers init function, ie, after OpenLayers has loaded.

```
OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar.prototype.zoomBarUp = function(evt){

  //copy here the code from the actual function
  if (!OpenLayers.Event.isLeftClick(evt) && evt.type !== "touchend") {
        return;
  }
  //rest of code .....


 //put in your check for zoom level here before calling this.map.zoomTo(zoomLevel);
 if(this.map.zoom<13){
     this.map.zoomTo(zoomLevel);
        this.mouseDragStart = null;
        this.zoomStart = null;
        this.deltaY = 0;
        OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
  }};
```

There may be a more elegant way, but this should work.

Comment: Can I describe map min zoom level?

Comment: What do you mean -- restrict to a min zoom level?

Comment: new ol.View({minZoom: 9, maxZoom: 13, ...}); http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/zoom-constrained.js